# Unable to Get JupyterLab Link

Tags: ssh, jupyter, google-cloud-datalab

Google recommends using:

gcloud compute instances describe --project NAME --zone ZONE INSTANCE | grep googleusercontent.com | grep datalab

But when I run this, nothing shows up. I can access the JupyterLab through normal SSH tunnelling however. How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This issue is because of the last `grep`. Your command should be like this:

```
gcloud compute instances describe --project NAME --zone ZONE INSTANCE | grep googleusercontent.com
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Where do you find the documents for this? Google must not have updated its documents on the actual cloud.

Comment: Actually I used the first command, then added the `| grep googleusercontent.com` and finally the third part. Adding the last grep will filter the output which will print nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The current datalab documentation appears to not ask this:

https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstart

```sh
datalab create ${INSTANCE} --project=${PROJECT} --zone=${ZONE}
datalab connect ${INSTANCE} --project=${PROJECT} --zone=${ZONE}
```

As I suspect you're doing, you may also:

```sh
gcloud compute ssh ${INSTANCE} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--zone=${ZONE} \
--ssh-flag="-L 8081:localhost:8080"
```

same-same.

Please reference the documentation that you're using in your question so that we may better help.

Comment: Sorry for not being as clear. When I open the deployment manager, it says "Suggested Next Steps." Under that heading, it then says, "Access the running Jupyter notebook"
We've already started a Jupyter notebook instance on the VM for your convenience. In order to get link that can be used to access Jupyter Lab run the following command.  That command is then: gcloud compute instances describe --project PROJECT --zone us-east1-d INSTANCE | grep googleusercontent.com | grep datalab

Comment: I assume the Deployment Manager template is out of date. There's probably a "feedback" option with it. I recommend you file this feedback there.